# Java class for extracting LTC SMPTE timecode from an audio signal?

Tags: java, audio, timecodes

Is anyone aware of an existing Java library for decoding a SMPTE signal?  I'm familiar with [libltcsmpte](http://ltcsmpte.sourceforge.net/) and [Javier Jaimovitch's Matlab code](http://www.somasa.qub.ac.uk/~MuSE/?p=201), which both do what I want, except that they're not coded in Java.  I'm trying to save myself the trouble of rewriting their code.  Does anyone know if this has been done already?

Many thanks,

D.

Comment: Does the Java code you have extract SMPTE timecodes out of an audio file? I've been also working on such application, Would you like to share that code to me?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I can't share the code.  If you'd like though, I could put you in touch with the freelance programmer that we hired to write it. He might be willing to send it to you (possibly for a fee). If you'd like his email, please send me a private message. My contact info is on my profile page.

Comment: Thanks man. But I did not find your email Id on the site. Would you mind providing me your personal email id or you could ping me at amit.2006.it@gmail.com?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but if you already have familiarity with libltcsmpte and accessing native code isn't a deployment issue for you, perhaps consider using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) for direct library access. There is additional performance overhead above a normal JNI call, but it might get you something working more quickly than building it yourself (assuming no other Java library exists for this).

Comment: Thanks Simeon. Ultimately we solved our problem by subcontracting another programmer to write us a Java class.  Still, I appreciate you taking the time to respond.  Maybe this comment will be of assistance to someone else.